# Angular Ng-Animate - Smoother Transitions

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

Using ng-animate to provide some transitions when a user clicks into a tab.

Simply using

```
.ng-enter{
    transition:0.50s;
    opacity: 0;
 }
.ng-enter-active{
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

which works a treat. However, the first time you click in it's somewhat sticky.

The view which is being transitioned into displays for a brief second before being transitioned into, so you see it twice almost. This only occurs on the first time round, on subsequent visits the transition works perfectly.

Is there a way then to make the animation smoother the first time round? The tabs are being displayed using a div with ng-include.

Comment: AngularJS version? Can you replicate it in Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

You have to target the animation on the tab elements, like this :

```
.tab.ng-enter {
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    opacity:1;
}
.tab.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity:0;
}
```

ngAnimate (like ngLeave, ngEnter, etc...) classes will be added to each element appearing/disappearing in the view, so in your case, it is needed to restrain your animation to only one element.

You can see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) too.

Comment: That seems to be disabling the animations for me.